# How to control opacity for kmz files in google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api, kmz, transparency-opacity

I need to load several kmz files at one time via Google Maps API, and want to control the opacity for some of the kmz files. Is there a way to do it?

I checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651930/using-a-kmllayer-object-within-the-google-maps-api-is-it-possible-to-allow-a-us, but the methods do not work for me.

By editing opacity via the css, the whole map's opacity will be changed...

Answer (score 1):

Please check out http://www.gavinharriss.com/code/opacity-control might be helpful for you.